# How to use Electron with a specific version of Chromium?

Tags: electron

I need make a project with Electron but I need to use Chromium version: 42.0.2289.1

Can I tell Electron to use a specific version of Chromium?

Comment: I guess it's not really clear to me why you'd want this but there's a [release](https://github.com/electron/releases#releases) page that shows that you'd have to use Electron 0.27.1 to use Chrome 42, but it's not that specific patch version

Comment: I need make dowgrande because I want enable flash player in browser electron. I try lot other thinks but not can. Do you can help me?